# Source Block: How can I set a custom rate of agent generation?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, event-simulation

I want to generate agents from Source blocks on a custom schedule
For example: 2000 agents in 1st hour, 4000 agents in 2nd hour, 2000 in the third hour

How can I create such a Source block?

I am trying with
"Arrival Schedule" and "Rate Schedule" but not sure if thats the right approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Arrival Schedule** is indeed a good way to approach the problem.

[image]

[image]

The above should reflect the scenario you mentioned.